# JAVA | Error en Scanner de tipo Char

Tags: java

No me funciona el `scanner` de `Char`. ¿Cual es el error?

```java
    var scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Proporciona el simbolo:");
    char simbolo = Char.parseChar(scan.nextLine());
```

¿hay que escanear a tipo `String` y luego pasarlo a `Char`?

```java
    var scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Proporciona el simbolo:");    
    String simbol = scan.nextLine();
    char simbolo = simbol.char;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe una opción tipo `scan.nextChar()`, en ese caso para leer un `char` se usa `next().charAt(0)`, el cual obtiene el primer carácter que se encuentre en la línea:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Proporciona el simbolo:");    
char simbolo = scan.next().charAt(0); //primer carácter de la línea leída
```

De este modo puede que coloques una frase completa cuando te pida que proporciones el símbolo, pero solo tomará el primer carácter de esta misma.

> **Resultado**

En este caso imprimo la variable `simbolo`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información en inglés: [Scanner y nextChar() en Java](https://tutorialspoint.dev/language/java/gfact-51-java-scanner-nextchar)

Answer (score 1):

Si estás esperando una línea de un único carácter, debes hacer algo como

```
char c = scan.next(".").charAt(0); //consume sólo un caracter
```

Answer (score 0):

String texto = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce un codigo de la tabla ASCII");
//Pasamos el String a int
int codigo = Integer.parseInt(texto);

```
    //Pasamos el codigo a caracter
    char caracter = (char) codigo;

    System.out.println(caracter);
```